# Delphi MT05 ECU mph to kph

Tags: motorcycle, electronic-control-module, brixton

Is there an ignition key sequence for changing MPH to KPH reading for a Delphi MT05 ECU? The bike is a Brixton BX125, had to perform a hard reset of the ECU to clear out a fault code and that switched my clock to MPH readings.

I don't have an OBD2 reader or the right software tools to read/write MCU settings, really hoping there's a sequence for this setting as well.

Here's a link to the [Delphi MT05 ECU manual](https://1drv.ms/b/s!Ag6MYejDK_5pnqIe5iOgUA3pvZZlVA) for context.
And one to the [Chinariders thread](http://chinariders.net/showthread.php?t=15675), with the reset sequence.

Comment: If you read the manual, does it tell you?

Comment: No, but it doesn't mention the reset sequence either (ignition key on/off 5 times really quick for ECU reset).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folks over at chinariders.net answered this one. Here's the sequence (tested on my bike, Brixton BX125 with Delphi MT05 ECU, works!) -

1. Turn iginition off for at least 15 seconds
2. Turn ignition on/off two times really quick (half a second or so each cycle)
3. Wait 15 seconds (with ignition off)
4. Turn ignition on, your readings should now be in the new measurement system

Source: [chinariders.net thread](http://chinariders.net/showthread.php?p=324942#post324942)

Answer (score 1):

The MT05 ECU has absolutely nothing to do with the display of vehicle speed in your dashboard.
The speed sensor sends the speed pulses directly to the dashboard. The dashboard has a microprocessor which calculates the displayed speed from the pulses that come from the wheel.

You can download **[HUD ECU Hacker](https://netcult.ch/elmue/hud%20ecu%20hacker/)** which shows you all the ECU parameters for the Delphi MT05 / MT05.2 / MT05.3 and the Rongmao MT05.

In the help file you also find a diagram of the ECU and see how it is connected. Although the ECU has an input pin (J1-15) which may be used for the vehicle speed sensor, this is rarely connected in any motorbike. This pin may also be used for other purposes depending on the calibration. If it is connected to the vehicle speed sensor, the only purpose is a speed limiter which is often used in scooters. But the ECU has no output pin which sends the vehicle speed to the dashboard. The ECU has only an output pin (J1-06) for the engine speed which may be displayed in RPM in the dashboard.

So whatever you change in the ECU it will not affect your vehicle speed display. This is managed 100% by your dashboard alone. And if there is any key sequence which affects the speed display it is the dashboard itself which detects this key sequence. The ECU has nothing to do with it.